# batch rename files by common unique value

Tags: python, rename

I have a folder containing over 500 images. and a text file with new names for these images. I have tried to create a renaming script in python but I am struggling with the robustness issue. I would like to rename the file by selecting the new name by unique identifier

I wrote this...

```
import os
import csv


img_dir = str(raw_input("Path to Images Folder as C:/path/to/IMAGES  : "))
os.chdir(img_dir)

newNames_file = str(raw_input("csv file path and name as C:/path/to/loc_data.csv  : "))

with open(newNames_file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    newNames = list(reader)


newNames = [l[0] for l in newNames]

print"Current Working Directory is:  " + os.getcwd()

path = os.getcwd()
filenames = [os.path.join(img_dir,fn) for fn in next(os.walk(img_dir))[2]]

assert len(filenames) == len(newNames)

for i in range(len(newNames)):
    os.rename(str(filenames[i]), str(newNames[i]))
```

but the results are unreliable.. e.g. the order inst guaranteed to match.

How can I use the unique ID to pass the correct value top the rename function?

the file names are raw e.g. `IMG_3036.tif`

and the new values are in the form `7700_50fpl_4_1_3036`

where 3036 is the unique ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write a script and i think it will do the trick.

You can rewrite the `get_name_uid` function to get your new files' uid and old files's uid if you want.

Make sure you change the glob name and new_names file name as you use.

```
import glob
import os

old_image_filenames = glob.glob('*.img')
new_names = open('new_names').read().strip().split(',')

def get_name_uid(name):
    uid = name.split('.')[0]
    uid = uid.split('_')[-1]

    return uid


def get_uid_filename_map(filenames, get_uid_func):
    uid_filename_map = {}
    for filename in filenames:
        uid_filename_map[get_uid_func(filename)] = filename

    return uid_filename_map

uid_old_filenames = get_uid_filename_map(old_image_filenames, get_name_uid)
uid_new_filenames = get_uid_filename_map(new_names, get_name_uid)

for uid in uid_old_filenames.keys():
    if uid in uid_new_filenames:
        os.rename(uid_old_filenames[uid], uid_new_filenames[uid])
```

The folder i run script before

```
$ ls 
new_names       play.py         zasdf_3036.img  zxcsdf_3037.img
```

after run script

```
$ ls
7700_50fpl_4_1_3036.img 7700_50fpl_4_2_3037.img new_names               play.py
```

file new_names

```
$ cat new_names
7700_50fpl_4_1_3036.img,7700_50fpl_4_2_3037.img
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a go

Comment: @ZiaRanks I add some example when run the code, modify some name if the code don't fit your situation .

Comment: I am getting an error in the new_names line, `[Errno 22]  invalid mode ('r') or filename`  I tried using all the different r"path/foo/bar' "path//foo//" and "path\\foo\\bar" but I cant get it to run... I will keep trying (Also.. I am writting this for a windows box)

Comment: What's error ? If you are using python2 , replace the input() to raw_input()

Comment: I did that too.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JES\Documents\Spatial Informatics Research\image renaming\imgRenameNew.py", line 31, in <module>
    new_names = open(path_to_namefile).read().strip().split(',')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: u'r"C:\\Users\\JES\\Documents\\Spatial Informatics Research\\image renaming\\new_img_names.csv"'`

Comment: I can get past it if I use `.` and `./new_img_names.csv` but this runs with no effect on the filenames.

Comment: ensure the `new_img_names.svc` , the `imgRenameNew.py` and the image s you want to rename is in same folder if you use `.` and `./new_img_names.csv` as path .

Comment: they are... I would paste but 500 images... in `$ ls`

Comment: got past that too... (dumb... my files are `.jpg` not `.img` but now I get this

Comment: `File "imgRenameNew.py", line 52, in <module>`
    `os.rename(os.path.join(path_to_img,uid_old_filename[uid]),os.path.join(path_to_img ,uid_new_filename[uid]))
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect` (line 52 is final line)

Comment: Well it seems `glob` path is not correct in windows. I will update the script that will no more need to enter path . Ensure they are all in same folder when you use .

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @KIDJourney. I will accept it as soon as it works!

Comment: Not yet, the functuons do but I havnt been able to mesh the two yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i made in the end. Thank you for your help and input.

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


import os
import glob
import csv
import numpy as np



# Establish path to images that need renamed
path_to_img = raw_input("your path to your imgs\n")
glob_name = os.path.join(path_to_img, '*.tif')
old_image_filenames = glob.glob(glob_name)


# Make list from csv of new names
path_to_namefile = raw_input('your path to name file\n')

f = open(path_to_namefile)
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_names = []

for i in csv_f:
    csv_names.append(i)

new_names = []
for i in csv_names:
    new_names.append(str(i)[2:-2])

print new_names



def get_name_uid(name):
    uid = name.split('.')[0]
    uid = uid.split('_')[-1]
    return uid

def get_uid_filename_map(filenames, get_uid_func):
    uid_filename_map = {}
    for filename in filenames:
        uid_filename_map[get_uid_func(filename)] = filename
    return uid_filename_map


uid_old_filename = get_uid_filename_map(old_image_filenames, get_name_uid)
uid_new_filename = get_uid_filename_map(new_names, get_name_uid)


for uid in uid_old_filename.keys():
    if uid in uid_new_filename:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path_to_img, uid_old_filename[uid]), os.path.join(path_to_img, uid_new_filename[uid]))
```

I had to work through the reading the csv part a bit. And i dont think there is actually a numpy module... not sure how that wound up in there but this works well so i didnt change it anymore.